# Why does Pythons "any()" function work on numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Why is it possible to use `any` directly as a function on a `numpy` array?

```
In [30]: any(np.zeros(4))>0
Out[30]: False
```

I thought numpy's `any()`-method was on the `array` itself?

Is this the `python` function or the actual `numpy` method?

Comment: Unless you've aliased it, it's a Python built-in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one-dimensional arrays it works because the built-in Python-`any`-function just requires an iterable with items that can be cast to `bool`s (and a one-dimensional array satisfies these conditions) but for multidimensional arrays it won't work:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> any(np.ones((10, 10)))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> np.any(np.ones((10, 10)))
True
```

That's because if you iterate over a array you iterate over the first dimension, if you have a multidimensional array you'll get an `array` (not a number) in each iteration. These `array`s can't be cast to `bool`s. So it throws the exception.

But `np.any` will be faster (in most cases) on arrays than `any` because it's aware of the input-type (`array`) and it can avoid the python iteration that `any` needs:

```
In [0]: arr = np.zeros((1000))

In [1]: %timeit any(arr)     
Out[1]: 215 µs ± 4.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit np.any(arr)  
Out[2]: 31.2 µs ± 1.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

As a side note, you probably wanted to use `any(np.zeros(4) > 0)` instead of `any(np.zeros(4))>0`.

The first one checks if any element in your array is above zero, while the second checks if the result of `any` (`True` if any element is **not** zero) is above zero.

Comment: Nice explanation and timing example. Are you sure about the side note though? `any(np.zeros(4)).__eq__(0)` ==> `True`, `any(np.zeros(4)).__lt__(0)` ==> `False` etc, which looks very much the same as "check if any element is equal to/above/… zero"

Comment: The comparison and arithmetic operators like `>` do element-wise operations/checks on an array, so I'm pretty sure. Except you wanted to check if the result of `any` is greater than `0`. For example `any(np.array([-1, 0, 0])) > 0` returns `True` but `any(np.array([-1, 0, 0]) > 0)` returns `False`. It depends what you need (and you haven't said) so maybe it's me who is wrong. :)

Comment: Ah see the distinction now :)

Answer (score 2):

A `numpy` array is iterable, which is all the built-in `any` expects of its argument. `any` returns `False` if all of the elements of the iterable are falsey, which all the zeros are. Then the comparison `False > 0` is also `False`, giving you the observed value.